# javascript and oracle database

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway so that i can connect to oracle database through javascript and access the database values

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where the JavaScript is running.

In most cases, it runs in a web browser, and that host environment doesn't provide any way to connect to a remote database. Some browsers have built in SQL databases (which were in the HTML 5 specification, I'm not sure if they still are), I think they use SQLite (certainly not Oracle).

If you want to connect to Oracle from a web browser, then you will need some sort of intermediary. This usually means a web server that provides an HTTP based API and uses Perl, PHP, ASP.NET, etc, etc to talk to the database.

Other host environments may provide an Oracle API, but you would have to be more specific about which one you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create an AJAX application building upon `Oracle PL/SQL Gateway`. See also http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_we.htm .

As it happens, I have long ago written about this: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/blog/2006/11/30.php .

Answer (score 0):

you can use server-side JScript, although this, i'm pretty sure, is only supported by iis. this is how you accomplish it anyways;

```
<%@Language="JScript"%>
<%
var sqlbeg = "SELECT * FROM sbc WHERE disp = 'F00' AND rec_uid IS NULL";
var aconn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
var recset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset");
aconn.Open("DSN=ACUSQL_SBC;UID=sbc;PWD=sbc;");
recset.Open(sqlbeg, aconn, 3, 3);
%>
```